# What is causing these /cache/xxx entries in our logs?

Tags: google-chrome, logging, browser

We have a valid url with the path '/some/url', but we are experiencing errors in our logs caused by the fact that something is attempting to access: '/some/url/cache/526402928a7041a5c61ae7da95c679c3' (an invalid url).

The '/some/url' part varies but the client rather consistently tries to get './cache/xxx'.

Does anyone know why the client is attempting to retrieve this url - which component/plugin is causing this?

The user agent is:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11

or

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the cause at:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132059

Likely caused by a malfunctioning extension: "Browser Companion Helper" part of "Ginyas Browser Companion